# How to make element go back to original position using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment

So, I'm making a navbar where , when I'll be clicking an icon it'll move a bit upwards. And it works fine. But the problem is the icon is now stuck permanently on that place. How do I make it go back to original place when I click somewhere else??

i tried searching on yt and google but idk how to search it up in short and due to that i didn't get anything useful. I'm very new in JavaScript so a simple explanation would be best for me.. tnx!!

Comment: Learn about event bubbling. You can listen for an event on window.document which will be triggered if the user clicks anywhere on the page. Reset the position of the icon when this event occurs, unless the click's event.target is on that icon

Comment: okee..tnx for that.. I'll learn more about event bubbling and how they work... much love!!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would put the icon in the label element, which was linked (via for) to the input radio. And I would link the position to label:checked (in CSS class) And when another icon is clicked (which is maked the same way), the previous icon is automatically unchecked (by radio). And I don't even need javascript :-)

Comment: Yaa tha would also work.. I know this method but the thing it requires a lot of coding. And I'm trying to make it a simple as possible using JavaScript.. And since I'm learning JavaScript I'll need to know anyway. I've used your told method before as well for making another navbar and that turned out amazing so now I'm trying to level things up a bit.. tnx for the suggestion tho.. much love!!